# datatables does not like alais in json output

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, coldfusion

I have a query like this this:

```
select status,count(errorid) as field1,errorid,template,line,error_message,error_type,max(id) as field2
FROM errors
group by status,errorid,template,error_message, error_type, line,field1,field2 
ORDER BY field1 desc
```

but when i output the json, i am always getting this error

> key [count(errorid) as field1] not found in query, columns are [STATUS,FIELD1,ERRORID,TEMPLATE,LINE,ERROR_MESSAGE,ERROR_TYPE,FIELD2]

I am literally lost how to make it work, do i need declare something on the server-side, client side, my `client JS` just includes the source to ajax call, no use of `cols`,

it goes into else clause where it do like this

```
<cfelse>
70:  `<cfsavecontent variable="any">#JSStringFormat(queryResult[tableFields[innerCounter]][counter])#</cfsavecontent>`
```

Comment: Have you done on `<cfdump>` of you query results to verify that the expected data is present?

Comment: A) That is a server side error saying you are using the wrong column name. You need to use the column alias "Field1", not "count(errorid) as Field1. ." B) Doesn't look like that will create valid json. Use serializeJson() instead.

Comment: yes, i dumped and i get the data, but when it goes into the JSOn portion where i had the datatables filtering going on, it crashes, Doing it on luce

Comment: but with serializeJSON, i might not be able to add additional information i want to to the fields

Comment: Yes, you can build whatever object you need, and serialize and return that. Give us a specific example, please...

Comment: Here is the Code I have for my work https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=521307c7-f0bd-4127-b9cf-90146ab08cc4/bc1bb8d5-4787-4108-9207-0387a9287dc0/39d843d2-a500-4295-999c-e290b82da2f6.cfm

Comment: ii shared my code, any clue how this can be fixed in

Comment: The cause of the error was already explained above. You're using the wrong column name when dynamically looping through the query:  "count(errorid) as Field1" instead of "Field1".   Beyond that, it's too much code for anyone to sift through, since no one can actually execute it.

Comment: i even tried using field1, it still goes into else clause and breaks there where it finds the above column count(eorrorid) as field1

Comment: Get rid of the nested save content. And try using "SerializeJSON(yourquery, 'struct')

Comment: with serialize, i do get data, but how do i modify my values now, like i want to use the <img atgs and other conditions

Comment: i managed to get the data as json, but it is appearing it like this, not sure why the object is coming, unable to load on datatables https://prnt.sc/twven3

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code from https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=521307c7-f0bd-4127-b9cf-90146ab08cc4/bc1bb8d5-4787-4108-9207-0387a9287dc0/39d843d2-a500-4295-999c-e290b82da2f6.cfm

..it does appear that you've been given the answer multiple times in the comments above but don't appear to have taken on the advice, unless you've already implemented that but haven't updated the cffiddle or the question?

You have several places between lines 57-68 where you are trying to access the column name using code like this:

```
queryResult[tableFields[innerCounter]][counter]
```

But your `tableFields` looks like this:

```
<cfset tableFields= ['status','count(errorid) as field1', 'errorid', 'template','line','error_message', 'error_type','max(id) as field2']>
```

So if any of your if/else conditions in your loop hit `field1` or `field2` then `tableFields[innerCounter]` is going to contain the aggregate function instead of just the aliased column name.

So to ensure you are using the aliased column name here, you could do this:

```
queryResult[listLast(tableFields[innerCounter]," ")][counter]
```

or for a long-handed approach, create a another copy of `tableFields` with just the column names, eg

```
<cfset tableFieldNames= ['status','field1', 'errorid', 'template','line','error_message', 'error_type','field2']>
```

...and use that instead of `tableFields` in the offending lines, eg
`queryResult[tableFieldNames[innerCounter]][counter]`

Comment: i had it fixed, just returned the query and then serialized the query and had to declare the columns in datatables data and it all works

Comment: i removed everything related to tableFields

Comment: Then you should post an answer that clearly shows the code changes made, and how it solved the problem. As it stands now, the solution is unclear so the thread only benefits you. Demonstrating how you solved the problem would turn this thread into something very useful, that benefited many others with the same problem in the future.